# How to turn 90 degrees to the axis of the date?

Tags: pgfplots

[image]

Rotate 90 degrees date. How to implement this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add `xticklabel style={rotate=90}` to the `axis` options. Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{dateplot}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  xticklabel style={rotate=90},
  date coordinates in=x,
  xticklabel={\day.\month.\year}
  ]
\addplot coordinates{(2015-01-05,42)(2015-06-20,24)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! And how to change the date format, instead of 2015.10.01 do 01.10.2015?

Comment: @perfection you should probably +1 and accept the answer as a means of saying thanks.

Comment: Now _that's_ service with a smile. :)

Comment: @perfection See updated answer.